# python code that calculate 4*(1-(1/3)+(1/5)-(1/7)+...+(1/2n-1))

Tags: python, python-3.7

I'm interested in math but I don't know a lot about coding on python I want to write a code in python that calculate:

4*(1-(1/3)+(1/5)-(1/7)+...+(1/2n-1))

that convergence to pi. I want a python code so that I import n for example 1,2,3,1000,...and see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here.

```
def pi_approx(n):
    return 4*sum([((-1)**i)/(2*i+1) for i in range(n)])
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain to OP what is happening here so they in fact learn from your answer.

Comment: I am of the opinion that dissecting the basic Python syntax on their own may help the OP develop better learning skills. In any case, I'll add an explanation if they ask for it, but not otherwise.